Environment Variables Not Loading Correctly in VSCode Terminal for Next.js Project
I work in VSCode on a Mac. Somehow, I found that my Next.js .env file isn't being loaded correctly. To debug this, I added some log statements in next.config.js to check if the environment variables are being loaded properly for server-side not client-side:
// import { withContentlayer } from "next-contentlayer";

console.log('Next.js Environment Variables:', process.env);
console.log('GITHUB_ID is: ', process.env.GITHUB_ID)

const { withContentlayer } = require("next-contentlayer");

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    domains: [
      "avatars.githubusercontent.com",
      "weijunext.com",
      "smartexcel.cc",
    ],
  },
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/github",
        destination: "https://github.com/weijunext/smart-excel-ai",
        permanent: false,
      },
    ];
  },
};

// export default withContentlayer(nextConfig)
module.exports = withContentlayer(nextConfig);

when I run
npm run dev

in vscode integrated terminal, the debug log output the wrong lines, the GITHUB_ID should not be empty in my env file
  ...
  GOOGLE_ID: '',
  GITHUB_ID: '',
  ...

But when I run the same command npm run dev in my iTerm2 terminal, it outputs the correct values:
  GITHUB_ID: 'Iv23lixxxxxxxx',
  GITHUB_SECRET: '1b5b2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  GOOGLE_ID: '123',
  GOOGLE_SECRET: '456',

My development env are

nextjs 13.5.6
macos sonoma 14.5
vscode 1.91.1
Shell  /bin/zsh

Additionally, my .env file is located in the root directory of my Next.js project and contains the following:
...
GITHUB_ID=Iv23lixxxxxxxx
GITHUB_SECRET=1b5b2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GOOGLE_ID=123
GOOGLE_SECRET=456
...

Can anyone help me resolve this issue? I would really appreciate it.
I tried uninstall npm and use pnpm, it also results in the same. Some of the variables in my .env seems to be cached somewhere.

What terminal emulator are you using in VSCode? It should show on the right of the terminal header (eg mine says zsh). Try running echo $SHELL in each and see what it says. Also run pwd in each terminal and see if they're the same

Items2 and vscode output the same /bin/zsh, the pwd output the same /Users/liujianan/Develop/smart-excel-ai

That's very odd. The terminal really shouldn't make any difference since Next.js just uses dotenv internally. The only thing I can think of is that you have exported overriding environment variables in one of your terminal sessions. Try env | grep GITHUB_ID, if anything shows up, there's your answer

I tried running the command, but the GITHUB_ID variable is not being output in the terminal. Now I'm trying to download a WebStorm to see if it also  face the same problem or not, thanks a lot.

My webstorm outputs are all correct, it very odd with my vscode, and I tried to remove vscode from mac and delete rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/ caches and .vscode dir and then reinstall, still the same.

"but the GITHUB_ID variable is not being output in the terminal"... is anything output though? Ideally you'd see nothing. If you see GITHUB_ID= it means you've exported it as an empty string. You could also try opening a new terminal in VSCode

Everything I exported  in my .env file is correct, GITHUB_ID is not an empty string. I tried again to do a full reinstall of my vscode on Mac, this time I need to login to vscode and load config from scratch. And after that I run the debug, now the output is correct, nothing changed at all. I can see the correct env log output. So it might be some vscode issue I think, but I can't reproduce it again.
